# What is wrong with my async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to execute an async series in nodejs with https://github.com/caolan/async#series :

```
async.series([
    function getLightsId(callback) {
        args = {
            path: {
                "username": "username"
            }
        };

        client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://bridgeip/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

        client.methods.getLightState(args, function (data, response) {
            var ids = [];
            for (key in data) {
                ids.push(key);
            }
            callback(null, ids);
        });
    },
    function getLightsState(ids, callback) {
        var lightsState = new Object();
        async.each(ids, function (id) {
            getLightState(id, function (state) {
                lightsState[id] = state;
            });
        });
        callback(null, lightsState);
    }
], function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

but its returning me this error :

callback(null, lightsState); TypeError : undefined is not a function.

I dont understand why..

How do i pass my object lightsState to my other function ?

Comment: maybe... `var lightsState = new Object();` isnt a function?

Comment: Well.. i declare a new object, so i can fill it in my each loop, whats wrong with this ?

Comment: We need to pass an OBJECT TYPE FUNCTION to the callback in the line `callback(null, lightsState);`

Comment: i am sorry, i dont understand, you can't pass an object in a callback ? it works with my array ids in the       `function getLightState`

Comment: Are you saying i get this error because my callback is not in a function ? but it is un my ` getLightsState` function.. i dont understand how am i supposed to do this.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get ids in your second task, but you'll get a callback as is described in docs.

You could do:

```
async.series([
    function getLightsId(callback) {
        args = {
            path: {
                "username": "username"
            }
        };

        client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://bridgeip/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

        client.methods.getLightState(args, function (data, response) {
            var ids = [];
            for (key in data) {
                ids.push(key);
            }
            callback(null, ids);
        });
    },
], function (err, result) {
  var ids = result[0]
  var lightsState = new Object();
  async.each(ids, function (id) {
      getLightState(id, function (state) {
          lightsState[id] = state;
      });
  });
});
```

But this goes against the conventional use-case of async.series, you only have one async  task there.
What you're after for is probably [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) - so here's how that would look like:

```
async.waterfall([
    function getLightsId(callback) {
        args = {
            path: {
                "username": "username"
            }
        };

        client.registerMethod("getLightState", "http://bridgeip/api/${username}/lights/", "GET");

        client.methods.getLightState(args, function (data, response) {
            var ids = [];
            for (key in data) {
                ids.push(key);
            }
            callback(null, ids);
        });
    },
    function getLightsState(ids, callback) {
        var lightsState = new Object();
        async.each(ids, function (id) {
            getLightState(id, function (state) {
                lightsState[id] = state;
            });
        }, function(err) { 
          callback(err, lightsState)
        });
    }
], function (err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Oh, and I thought that `async.each` needed a callback. I'm not sure, maybe it was you intention not to be so?

Comment: Thanks you ! a lot ! its a lot clearer in my head :)

Answer (score 0):

> its returning me this error:  `callback(null, lightsState); TypeError : undefined is not a function.`

Because `callback` is not a function. Only the first argument that is passed to your `function getLightsState(ids, callback) {` is one. Check [the docs for `series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#series):

> `tasks` - An array or object containing functions to run, each function is passed a 
>    callback(err, result)
>   `series(tasks)` runs the functions in the  tasks  array in series, each one running once the previous function has completed.

In contrast, these are the [docs for the `waterfall` function](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) - which is what you want:

> Runs the  tasks  array of functions in series, each **passing their results to the next** in the array.

---

Btw,

> ```
>     var lightsState = new Object();
>     async.each(ids, function (id) {
>         getLightState(id, function (state) {
>             lightsState[id] = state;
>         });
>     });
>     callback(null, lightsState);
> ```

is unlikely to work, you probably want to use [`reduce`](https://github.com/caolan/async#reduce) instead:

```
async.reduce(ids, {}, function(lightsState, id, rcallback) {
    getLightState(id, function(state) {
        lightsState[id] = state;
        rcallback(null, lightsState);
    });
}, callback);
```

Comment: `rcallback` has the signature `(err, reduction)`.

Comment: Thanks you too, it helped a lot, indeed my async.each was not working. thanks !